# Picking out balls in an urn

Tags: combinatorics

I was thinking to find the probability that Eric gets a $1$ and then what the probability Carlo will get a 6 if it has to be greater than one. So it would be $\frac{1}{10}*\frac{1}{9}$. But after figuring out the probability for when Eric gets a $2$ and a $3$ and so on, it seemed wrong and the calculations were way to big to calculate so I’m definitely doing something wrong. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of ways that Carlos getting a $6$ while still being higher than Eric is $5$(Eric can get $1$ to $5$). The total number of ways to pick out of the urn when Carlos's number is higher than Eric's number is $\frac{10*9}{2}=45$(See saulpatz's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3577053/picking-out-balls-in-an-urn/3577073?noredirect=1#comment7354631_3577073)). That makes the conditional probability:$$\frac{5}{45}=\frac{1}{9}$$(I think I may have oversimplified the problem but in my head this makes perfect sense. Please tell me if I got anything wrong. I am only in the eighth grade so I am quite new to these maths)

Comment: It is correct but, $\binom{10}{2}$ is the number of ways where Eric is higher than Carlos. Without restrictions total ways are $\binom{10}{2} \cdot 2!$

Comment: @saulspatz Don't we also have to consider the possibilities where Carlos doesn't get a $6$? The probability can't be that high, right?

Comment: @saulspatz Um I don't think that we were given that Carlos got a $6$. We were only given that Carlos's number is higher than Eric's number. We were trying to find the probability of Carlos having a $6$ **given that Carlos's number is higher than Eric's number**.

Comment: @AidenChow You're right; I got it backwards.  Getting late here.

Comment: @saulspatz That's all right. Glad we cleared up the confusion.

Comment: The original answer was correct, but not the reasoning.  There are $90$ ways to draw $2$ numbers, and in half of them, Carlos's number is higher than Eric's.  Therefore, the denominator should be $45$, but not for the reason you stated.  Sorry if I confused you.

Comment: OK I edited my answer. It is now correct.

Comment: Yes, good work.

Comment: The phrase "Given that ..." indicates that we are dealing with a conditional probability. So, the sample space is restricted to the outcomes where Carlo's number is higher than Eric's one. These are exactly $\frac{10\cdot 9}{2}=45$ possible outcomes. Among those outcomes there are exactly $5$ where Carlo has got a $6$. That's why the CONDITIONAL probability is $\frac 5{45}=\frac 19$.

Comment: @AidenChow : The total number of ways to pick two numbers - since ordering matters - is $10\cdot 9$ and not $45$ as you now are stating in your answer. But because of the condition the consideration is restricted to those where Carlo's number is higher than Eric's one.

Comment: @trancelocation ok fixed it.

Comment: @AidenChow : This is ok now but instead of saying "total"  probability you may rather say "conditional" probability, since a conditional probability is to be found.

Answer (score 0):

Bayes theorem in this case states:

$$P(C=6|C>E) = \frac{P(C>E|C=6) P(C=6)}{P(C>E)} = \frac{.5 \cdot .1}{.45} = .1111 = \frac{1}{9}$$.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an expansion / complement to *Aiden*'s answer.

The pair of balls extracted represents a point in a $10 \times 10$ square.

[image]

Since you said that the extraction is simultaneous, that means that it is withour replacement,
so that we are graying out the diagonal.

Carlo's numbers being higher than Eric's means that we are considering only the part below the diagonal, 
which consists of $10 \cdot 9 / 2 = 45$ possible points.

Carlo drawing a six corresponds to the yellow column.

So the answer is $5/45 = 1/9$.